# Standard deviation of the product of gaussians

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

What is the standard deviation of the product of two random variables that each have Gaussian Distributions? I don't even know where to begin on this problem.

Comment: Are the random variables independent?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes! I'm led to believe that it should be something like $\delta A/\mu A +\delta B/\mu B$ from the following link, but their "proof" doesn't have much of a backing to it... (Page 33) http://physicsed.buffalostate.edu/pubs/MeasurementAnalysis/MA1_9ed.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be **independent** random variables each with normal distribution (the means and variances need not be the same). Let $W=XY$. Then
$$\text{Var}(W)=E((XY)^2)-(E(XY))^2.$$
We need to compute the two expectations on the right.

By independence, $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$. Also, $E(X^2Y^2)=E(X^2)E(Y^2)$.

Since $E(X^2)=\text{Var}(X) +(E(X))^2$, with a similar expression for $E(Y^2)$, once we know the mean and variance of $X$ and $Y$, we can use the above equations to find $\text{Var}(XY)$.

**Added**: Let the means be $\mu$ and $\nu$, and the variances be $\sigma^2$ and $\tau^2$. Then the variance of $XY$ is, by the above argument, equal to 
$$(\sigma^2+\mu^2)(\tau^2+\nu^2)-\mu^2\nu^2.$$
This simplifies to $\sigma^2\tau^2+\sigma^2\nu^2+\tau^2\mu^2$.

Note that we did not use the normality of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Statistical Independence between random variable has nothing to do with having the same means and variances. It is about having joint probability equals the product of probabilities.